# How to Minify CSS with SCSS File Watcher in PHPStorm IDE

Tags: sass, minify, phpstorm, yui-compressor

Is there a way to configure SASS FileWatcher so it builds a Minified CSS?

I currently configured SASS + YUI Compressor to accomplish this but I would like to do this with pure SASS if possible.

Here are the screenshots of both configurations:

[SASS](http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/2613/0hdj.png)

[YUI Compressor CSS](http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/8789/i4ve.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you checked command line arguments? SASS compiler (scss.bat) supports `--style compressed` option, which will produce **very compact/compressed** output -- http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style . If you wish -- you can then process it again with YUICompressor (to *possibly* obtain few more optimisations). **Alternatively** create a .BAT/.CMD file that would compile sass code first and then run it trough YUIC (2 lines in total) and use it in your File Watcher instead of actual SASS compiler.

Comment: @LazyOne That should be an answer. :)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Probably the fastest way to achieve this is to use the compressed option, mentioned in the previous comments, as an argument. The quickest way to configure this in PHPStorm is as follows:

- Go to `File > Settings`
- Inside `Project Settings` select `File Watchers`
- You should already have an SCSS watcher created here (if you have the SCSS watch plugin enabled, PHPStorm prompts you to create a watcher when opening a new .scss file.) Otherwise, enable it (more info about that in this section of the [official documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html),) and then  create the new watcher pressing the "+" symbol.
- Double click the watcher name to access its configuration.
- In the `Arguments` line make sure to add the `--style compressed` argument
- Click OK and you're done

This image shows how that configuration should look:

[image: Compressed SCSS settings in PHPStorm]

From that point on, your .css output files will be compressed.

Comment: here is the full Arguments:

--no-cache --style compressed --update $FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.css

Comment: Old but still valid. I had to put the arguments before the $FileName$ for it to work. (I tried it after before looking it up)

Answer (score 5):

```
The correct answer is --style=compressed
```

menu File -> Settings -> Tools - File watchers
add scss and in argument add --style=compressed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **sassc** under Linux (Arch) you could use as Arguments:

```
-t compressed -m auto $FileNameWithoutExtension$.scss $FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.css
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, `--style compressed`, `--style compressed` and `--style=compressed` don't work.

I had to add the option `-x` as an argument.

Like here:
[image]

If you want more details this post the following post is where I found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25579991/9861577.

Comment: That's because you are using LESS and this is about SCSS