# What is the best way to get minified CSS output from LESS?

Tags: less, minify

Is it possible to get minified compiled CSS from LESS automatically?
Every time I change something, I have to manually compress it.

I use less.js to compile LESS.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're using the Less compiler, in order to output minified CSS,  pass the `-x` option. This is documented: http://lesscss.org/#using-less-command-line-usage

Comment: @HashemQolami you should make this an answer.

Comment: Many IDEs have plugin that does LESS compilation and CSS minification automatically. E.g. Web Essentials in VS 2012 or above. Not sure if it's useful since you didn't mention what environment you're using.

Answer (score 29):

`$ lessc styles.less -x`  The compress command has been deprecated.

> you'll have to use this command `$ lessc -clean-css style.less
>   style.min.css`

before use above command you've to install **less-plugin-clean-css** using below command

```
$ npm install less-plugin-clean-css -g
```

Answer (score 20):

If you are using the Less command-line compiler, you could pass the `-x` option in order to output minified CSS.

```
$ lessc styles.less -x
```

This is documented in [Less doc](http://lesscss.org/#using-less-command-line-usage):

> To output minified CSS, simply pass the `-x` option. If you would like
>   more involved minification, the [Clean CSS](https://github.com/GoalSmashers/clean-css) is also available with the
>   `--clean-css` option.
>
> To see all the command line options run lessc without parameters.

Comment: Actually, I use less.js to compile LESS.

Comment: @Jay Less.js does all the things in front-end side, therefore minifying the output doesn't make sense.

Comment: Oh. So Hashem can you suggest a way where I can make website more fast with minified output? Sorry for the same question. Getting confused.

Comment: IMHO If you really care about the performance, it's better to compile Less files and compress the output on your local system, Then `<link>` the minified version of the output (which is CSS) into your HTML pages.

Comment: `-x` is presently deprecated

Answer (score 9):

According to [github README.md](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-clean-css#readme) for minification you should use this command:

```
lessc file.less --clean-css="--s1 --advanced --compatibility=ie8"
```