# File Watcher in PhpStorm minify and normal CSS

Tags: css, phpstorm, minify, file-watcher

I've read this question:
[How to Minify CSS with SCSS File Watcher in PhpStorm IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982845/how-to-minify-css-with-scss-file-watcher-in-phpstorm-ide#22131565).

And it was very helpful. But I want to have a *normal* stylesheet, where I can see the lines in development. And I want a *minified* stylesheet for the live environment.

Can this be done with 1 file watcher? Because now I have 2, and it creates 2 `.map` files: `style.css.map` and `style.min.css.map`. I don't like that.

Comment: Tell it not to produce `.map` file for the second one?

Comment: SCSS compiler can't produce both non-minified and minified CSS at the same time. if you need a single file watcher, you can create a batch script that would run SCSS for your .scss file to produce a .css and then run some uglifier (YUI compressor, etc) on generated file, and configure this script as a watcher. or, use a build tool (gulp/grunt/etc) to pertform both tasks, and either set them up as watchers, or use their `watch` tasks

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working now. Like @lazyone said, just don't generate a .map for the minified sheet.

This is how you do it:

In `arguments` field, you add: `--no-cache --style compressed --update --sourcemap=none $FileName$:../$FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.css`

the `sourcemap=none` part should do the trick.